# How to create a dataset of type Azure Data Lake storage Gen 2 in data factory?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake, azure-data-lake-gen2

I want to create a dataset of type Azure Data Lake storage Gen 2 in data factory. I followed the steps:

1. Click on "New Dataset"
2. In "Select data store", I selected "Azure data lake storage gen 2" and hit "continue"
3. In "choose format type of your data", I do not want to select any particular format but this is a mandatory step.

How do I create the required dataset without having to select a particular format in Step 3?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, no, you must select a particular format in Step 3.

About file formats in Data Lake Gen 2, you can refer to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-data-lake-storage#dataset-properties).